# Add exception to R code

Tags: r, exception, dataframe

With help from SO user I've got the following properly working code that gets info from API about the book based on vector of ISBN numbers. During last iteration the code is supposed to merge data from lists to one data.frame.
Unfortunately, some ISBNs are incorrect and during map_2df function it receives an error (because the retrieved list is incorrect).

How can I add an exception for such errors? 
P.S. The last ISBN in example vector is incorrect

```
    library(purrr)

isbns<- c("9785170857098", "9785170840601", "9785170916900", "9785170640966", "9785669656714")
# Paste is vectorized, so make a list of URLs all at once. 
# `httr` can make a URL out of a list of named parameters, if it's more convenient.
results <- paste0("http://www.knigoed.info/api/Prices?code=", 
                  isbns, 
                  "&sortPrice=DESC&country=RU") %>% 
        # Iterate over vector of URLs, using fromJSON to pull and parse the request.
        # map, like lapply, will put the results into a list. 
        map(jsonlite::fromJSON, flatten = FALSE)

# Grab "prices" element of each top-level list element
results %>% map('prices') %>% 
        # Iterate in parallel (like mapply/Map) over prices and isbns, making a data.frame of
        # each. map2_df will coerce the resulting list of data.frames to a single data.frame.
        map2_df(isbns, ~data.frame(isbn = .y, .x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.rows=FALSE)) %>%
        # assign data frame to analyzedData
         {.} -> analyzedData
```

Comment: Look at `?try` -- you can check how code evaluated, then use if/else statements to return what you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Purrr library, use `safely()` function to create safe functions which will allow you to capture results and error, at the same time will complete the tasks for which you have correct ISBNs.

```
safe_map <- safely(map)

# Grab "prices" element of each top-level list element
analyzedData <- results %>% 
                  safe_map(.f = ~ {rep_len <- length(.x$prices$priceValue);
                                   data.frame(isbn             = rep(.x$code, rep_len), 
                                              priceValue       = .x$prices$priceValue, 
                                              stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                                              check.rows       =FALSE)})

str(analyzedData)

res <- do.call(rbind, analyzedData[["result"]])
errs <- do.call(rbind, as.list(analyzedData[["error"]]))
library("dplyr")
isbn_prices <- res %>% 
                 group_by(isbn) %>%
                 filter(isbn %in% isbns)

> isbn_prices
Source: local data frame [15 x 2]
Groups: isbn [4]

            isbn priceValue
           (chr)      (dbl)
1  9785170857098       1119
2  9785170857098        992
3  9785170857098        899
4  9785170857098        899
5  9785170857098        899
6  9785170857098        899
7  9785170857098        712
8  9785170857098        449
9  9785170840601        535
10 9785170840601        451
11 9785170840601        445
12 9785170840601        392
13 9785170916900        662
14 9785170916900        199
15 9785170640966        445
> errs
NULL
```